# Get the current store -Ext JS

Tags: extjs, grid, store

Simple question here,

I have a grid in my application that can hold one of any 3 given stores (utlizes bindStore() function).

Is there a function to retrieve the current store? Something like: `Ext.getStore(grid.currentStore());`

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Solution was much easier than I thought. All I had to do was: `var store = Ext.getCmp('grid').getStore();'

Answer (score 0):

`Ext.StoreMgr.lookup('store id');` will return store for you.

Comment: Thanks Riku. Ext.getStore('myStore'); is the shorgut to that I believe.